# How to get the second last word which has more than one letters from a string in oracle plsql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to get the second last word from a string which has more than one letter from a string in plsql.

For eg :-

IF string is 'John Smith A' I need to get 'Smith' as the out put.

If string is 'John Smith An' I need to get 'An' as the out put.

I have tried the following; its regex is working in the regex tester but when it comes to oracle plsql it is not giving any out put.

```
SELECT regexp_substr('John Smith A', '([a-zA-Z]{2,}[^a-zA-Z]*)(?!.*[a-zA-Z]{2,}[^a-zA-Z])') FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sql
SELECT regexp_substr('John Smith A', '([[:alpha:]]+)(\s+[[:alpha:]])?$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

See the  [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dklCTu/1).

The pattern matches:

- `([[:alpha:]]+)` - Group 1: one or more letters
- `(\s+[[:alpha:]])?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `[[:alpha:]]` - a single letter
- `$` - end of string

Comment: FYI: Also, see a demo at [Rextester](https://rextester.com/VMMGM24140).